# IE (mobile) does not show subitems on touch

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello I got a question regarding showing a sublist on touch. I created a sublist which will be shown if you hover over it, see [demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/9zp5k7ej/1/):

```css
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:400,200,300,600,700);
 body {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  margin: 50px;
}
a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.wrapper {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
.wrapper a {
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 25px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-right: 9px;
  padding-left: 9px;
  padding-top: 5.5px;
  padding-bottom: 8.5px;
}
.subitems {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  float: left;
  min-width: 160px;
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #245d94;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
  box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
.wrapper a:hover + .subitems {
  display: block;
  background-color: #245d94;
}
.wrapper a:hover + .subitems a {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
}
.subitems > a {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #fff;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.subitems:hover {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="#">
    TOUCH ME 1
  </a>
  <div class="subitems">
    <a href="#">ITEM 1.1</a>
    <a href="#">ITEM 1.2</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="#">
    TOUCH ME 2
  </a>
  <div class="subitems">
    <a href="#">ITEM 2.1</a>
    <a href="#">ITEM 2.2</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Whenever I **touch** my 1 / 2 buttons within Chrome/Firefox it will show the submenu. But for some reason IE will not. Can anyone tell me why? And how could I solve that?

I did not create any jQuery code. I just use the standard browser functionality. If jQuery code is needed to make this work. I am fine with that.

P.S Keep in mind that I only focus on touch events not mouse clicks.

Comment: by touch you mean hover?

Comment: @apieceofbart no really touching (like  you press on a touch device where hover is not available)

Comment: should have wrote *IE Mobile*

Comment: On which device are you testing?

Comment: @empiric on a surface tablet and a lenovo touch supported ultrabook

Comment: @empiric awesome! That did the trick! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152141(v=vs.85).aspx) article from Microsoft I tested it on a Windows-phone with IE 10/11 mobile.

Adding the `aria-haspopup="true"` attribute will work for the first click, as it simulates the `hover`-event.

```
<a href="#" aria-haspopup="true">
    TOUCH ME 2
</a>
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/9zp5k7ej/4/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure IE is running in standards mode - put in a doctype like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

Refer the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa358818(VS.85).aspx)

Adjacent sibling selector (+ sign in css) :
1,Requires Windows Internet Explorer 7 or later.

2,Combinators are enabled only in standards-compliant mode (strict !DOCTYPE).